# How to do distance calculation and clustering for event sequences in TraMineR?

Tags: r, traminer

I've been using TraMineR for a while now, even though I consider myself a begginer user. The same goes for R language.

Yet, I've been able to successfully perform a few optimal matching analysis. Now I'm trying to do the same for event sequences, but I actually can't find the functions for it, neither in the documentation nor in the user guide.

Is there any `seqedist` function or something of the sort ? (as opposed to `seqdist`, but taking an event sequence as an input) I appreciate the help, thanks !

Comment: You might find that this question is a better fit for stats.stackexchange.com rather than here (that's the statistics site, CrossValidated). Are you asking more of a methods or more of a programming question?

Comment: hey @TARehman thanks for the advice. What I really wanna know are the functions available in the package so I guess it is more programming oriented. Still it would make no harm to try the CrossValidated as well. Thanks !

Comment: I'll flag your question to be migrated over to CV, I suspect they will be able to answer better.

Comment: well, as it is in kind of a grey area I'd appreciate if you could refrain from it for a limited ammount of time. specially given that I know a couple of very wise users that do usually have good answers for TraMineR questions in stack overflow. Gilbert for instance. thanks anyway !

Comment: See [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153252/how-to-do-distance-calculation-and-clustering-for-event-sequences-in-traminer?answertab=active#tab-top) on CrossValidated.